# Create non editable attribute for object in django

Tags: python, django

I'm currently trying to develop an app in django 1.10. I would like to know how I can initialize the attributes of an object in a one to many relationship at creation.

Let's call the two related objects 'Set' (one) and 'Element' (many).

The attribute 'name' of the object 'Set' is depending on the date and the number of other objects of the same kind already created. In this case I had no problem in initializing the values to the value I was interested in.

However the attribute 'name' of the object 'Element' is depending on the number of other Elements created but also the 'name' of the 'Set' it is linked to. How can I obtain this information?

I tried creating a method using as variable the ForeignKey value, but I was only obtaining an error in return. I tried something like:

```
// in models.py
def get_element_name(set_id):
    set = Set.objects.get(pk=set_id)
    set_name = set.name

    return set_name +'other stuff'

class Set(models.Model):
   // set attributes

class Element(models.Model):
   set = models.ForeignKey(Set, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250, editable=False, default=get_element_name(set.pk))
```

I can see how this is wrong (the ForeignKey has no pk attribute), but I couldn't find any other solution to my problem.

---

(What I would like to obtain in practice: The name of the Set is made by a letter, corresponding to the year of creation, and a number that is increased every time a new object is created. A001 is the first set created in the 2017, A002 the second, whilst B001 is the first of 2018 etc... The code of the elements should be instead the name of the set plus one letter according to the number of other elements created in that set. E.g. A001A is the first element of the set A001, A001B the second etc...)

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. Can you explain more what do you want element's name to be? Maybe by an example?

Comment: Can you provide the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting the error: AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'pk'

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think you can't set the default directly in the field definition. Instead, you can set this default in the `save` method of the `Element` model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.name = self.set.name + 'other stuff'
    # or self.name = get_element_name(self.set.id) if you prefer, but it does an unusefull call to db
    return super(Element, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```